# Is there any solution to this powershell script issue? I've tried many different solutions

Tags: c#, powershell, error-handling, command

```
$serverPath = "${V:\} + $Global:certRequestID "
        $localPath = "${C:\temp\} + $Global:certRequestID "



    # Check for atsinst.bat first - run it if it exists. Else offer uninstall/install options
        
            if(Test-Path -LiteralPath "${localPath}\install\atsinst.bat") {
                Invoke-Expression -Command "${localPath}\install\atsinst.bat -DeployMode 'Silent' " | Out-Host
            }

            Else{
                Copy-Item -Path $serverPath -Destination $localPath -Recurse -Force | Out-Host
                
                Write-Host "`nUninstalling ${certRequestID}: "
                Invoke-Expression -Command "${localPath}Deploy-Application.exe" -DeployMode 'Silent' -DeploymentType 'Uninstall' | Out-Host
            

            
                Write-Host "`nInstalling ${certRequestID}: "
                Invoke-Expression -Command "${localPath}Deploy-Application.exe" -DeployMode 'Silent' | Out-Host
                }
            
        }
```

Currently im getting this error:

> A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'DeployMode'.
> + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
> + PSComputerName        : WKPF26YSKX

Answer (score 0):

You need to have double quotes around the whole `-Command` parameter. I think the second issue is that you have to use the [dot source operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#dot-sourcing-operator-) (`.`  e.g. a dot and a space) in front of the command to execute it, e.g.

```
Invoke-Expression -Command ". ${localPath}Deploy-Application.exe -DeployMode 'Silent' -DeploymentType 'Uninstall'" | Out-Host

...

Invoke-Expression -Command ". ${localPath}Deploy-Application.exe -DeployMode 'Silent'" | Out-Host
```

Comment: Hmm i did that and now i get the following error Installing : 
The term '-DeployMode' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-DeployMode:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
    + PSComputerName        : WKPF26YSKX

Comment: Try [dot sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#dot-sourcing-operator-) before the command. This tells PowerShell to execute the following .exe. (see edit)